# C++ header file and CPP file

Tags: c++, header

I have created my class inside a header file named `Phone.h` now I have a `PhoneC.cpp` which is where I define my functions from `Phone.h` and then my `main.cpp` which is where I declare the int main and so forth. Though I am getting an error of

```
one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I'm not too sure what this means nor did any other post explain to what the fix is blatantly enough.

**Phone.h**

```
#ifndef PHONE_IMEI_API
#define PHONE_IMEI_API

#include <string>
    class Phone {

        public:
            bool checkIMEI(std::string IMEI);
            void sort();
            std::string data[5] = {};
        } Phone;

#endif
```

**PhoneC.cpp**

```
#include "Phone.h";

bool Phone::checkIMEI(std::string IMEI)
{
    int IMEIlength = 15;
    int len, i, mul, sum, m10;
    len = IMEI.length();
    char chksum = IMEI[len];
    i = 0;

    if (len != IMEIlength)
        return false;

    mul = 2; sum = 0;

    for (i = len - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int currentNumber = static_cast<int>(IMEI[len]);
        if (currentNumber * mul >= 10)
            sum += ((currentNumber * mul) / 10) + ((currentNumber * mul) % 10);
        else
             sum += currentNumber * mul;

       if (mul == 2)
          mul = 1;
       else
          mul = 2;
    }

   m10 = sum % 10;
   if (m10)
       m10 = 10 - m10;


   if (m10 == chksum)
       return true;
   else
       return false;

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Phone.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    string imei;

    cout << "Please enter an IMEI" << endl;
    cin >> imei;

    if (Phone.checkIMEI(imei))
    {
        cout << "Hello World";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Not to sure what I did wrong I tried following the documentation from [this official documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) still no luck. thanks for any obvious suggestions, not complete with lessons on C++

Comment: In phone.H, `class Phone { ... } Phone;` is this some new C++ism I'm not familliar with?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/  is where I got that from. It states the second determination is the Object name. So I could change Phone to Cell and then `Cell.checkIMEI(imei);` at least this is what I am getting from the read if I am wrong just slap me silly

Comment: Havent run the code to test myself, but i'm "somehwat" sure that changing the second phone to Cell may fix your problem. The compiler is probably getting confused by having two things with the same name there.

Comment: Ahh, hadn't even though it was creating an instance of the object. This is your issue - everything that include phone.h creates a variable called Phone. You want to make your instance in a .cpp file.

Comment: The `class Phone { ... } Phone;` creates both a class with identifier "Phone" and an instance of that class with the same name (that's allowed, but forces you to say "class Phone" when you want to refer to the class later in the program).  Then you include that header from both translation units (.cpp files) - that's why it's reporting "multiply defined" - there are two `Phone` objects.  Just delete the second use of `Phone` from the header, and in `main()` add `Phone phone;` to create a local instance of the class `Phone`, then `phone.checkIMEI(...)` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was wrong is the same `Phone` as class and the object name. So what I did was

```
#ifndef PHONE_IMEI_API
#define PHONE_IMEI_API

#include <string>
    class Phone {

        public:
            bool checkIMEI(std::string IMEI);
            void sort();
            std::string data[5] = {};
        };

#endif
```

**PhoneC.cpp**

```
#include "Phone.h";

bool Phone::checkIMEI(std::string IMEI)
{
    int IMEIlength = 15;
    int len, i, mul, sum, m10;
    len = IMEI.length();
    char chksum = IMEI[len];
    i = 0;

    if (len != IMEIlength)
        return false;

    mul = 2; sum = 0;

    for (i = len - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int currentNumber = static_cast<int>(IMEI[len]);
        if (currentNumber * mul >= 10)
            sum += ((currentNumber * mul) / 10) + ((currentNumber * mul) % 10);
        else
             sum += currentNumber * mul;

       if (mul == 2)
          mul = 1;
       else
          mul = 2;
    }

   m10 = sum % 10;
   if (m10)
       m10 = 10 - m10;


   if (m10 == chksum)
       return true;
   else
       return false;

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Phone.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Phone phone;
    string imei;

    cout << "Please enter an IMEI" << endl;
    cin >> imei;

    if (phone.checkIMEI(imei))
    {
        cout << "Hello World";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And that seemed to work. If any suggestions to why and what I did wrong. Please post the answer. Or I'll just mark this as correct. -_-